# google maps in subview

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I am using google maps in my application with a marker.
I am able to hold and drag the marker and tap on map and change the marker position.

Now i want to move the marker on being dragged or when the map is dragged.
and also i want to print the address of the markers location as the pop up on the map on being touched. 
I have found many codes in objective c but converting swift is little difficult for me. i am attaching my code below till what i have done.

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController , GMSMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var Next: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var MyAnnotation: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var MyMapView: GMSMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       Next.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        MyMapView.delegate = self

    load()

}

    func load() {

        //map hardcoded

        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 30.307182, longitude: -97.755996, zoom: 5)

        MyMapView.camera = camera

        MyMapView.delegate = self



        //marker hardcoded

        let marker = GMSMarker()

        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 30.307182, longitude: -97.755996)



        marker.icon = UIImage(named: "Annotation")

        //  london.map = mapView

        marker.map = MyMapView

        ////hardcoded

        marker.isDraggable =  true



    }
 func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

//        print("You tapped at \(coordinate.latitude), \(coordinate.longitude)")

        print("You tapped at \(coordinate.latitude), \(coordinate.longitude)")

        MyMapView.clear() // clearing Pin before adding new

        let marker = GMSMarker(position: coordinate)

         marker.icon = UIImage(named: "Annotation")

        marker.map = MyMapView

        marker.title = " "

        marker.userData = " "

        marker.isDraggable = true

    }

}
```

Comment: "markers location as the pop up on the map" - actual readable address?

Comment: @Mr.Bista yes same